# iOS app is not visible as a result in Google Search

Tags: ios, itunes, google-search

2 months ago I uploaded an iOS app to the App Store. Right now it is visible on the App Store and in iTunes, but while searching my iOS app in Google search it is not showing my app link. But if I search any other iOS apps in Google search it is showing. Do I need to add any code to my app to get it to show?

Comment: What? You want your app to visible in google and add code for that? That makes no sense. If it's in the App Store it gets indexed by google and should be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not need to add any code to your app for this to show up. The main reason your app isn't showing up is probably because it hasn't had enough views on its own to provide a search result. No matter what adding code would not help because you aren't the owner of the iOS App Store domain, therefore meaning that you cannot make changes to its code.